# Prevent repeated row from returning in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have three tables in restaurant search done in php. The search has option to filter it by multiple type by checkbox state. Some restaurant may come under multiple type and will have multiple entry in type_stack table.

```
Table1 - **restaurant**
------+----------+----------
  id  +   name   +   place
------+----------+----------
   1      rest1       ny
   2      rest2       la
   3      rest3       ph
   4      rest4       mlp


Table2 - **r_type**
------+----------+----------
  id  +   name   +   code
------+----------+----------
   1      type1       0
   2      type2       1
   3      type3       2
   4      type4       3


Table3 - **type_stack**
------+----------+----------
  id  + rest_id  +   type
------+----------+----------
   1      2          2
   2      4          1
   3      1          2
```

I want to get all the restaurants that qualify under the types user have selected. But the problem is 1'm getting the same restaurant multiple times. I only want a row to be shown one time.

This is my query

```
SELECT restaurant.name, restaurant.place FROM restaurant, type_stack WHERE restaurant.id = type_stack.rest_id AND type_stack.type = '0' AND type_stack.type = '1' AND type_stack.type = '2' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The query is made based on checkbox state! In this case type 0, 1 and 2 are selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your statement into (you need DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT restaurant.name, restaurant.place FROM restaurant, type_stack WHERE restaurant.id = type_stack.rest_id AND type_stack.type = '0' AND type_stack.type = '1' AND type_stack.type = '2' LIMIT 0 , 30
```